# Graph Theory Ramsey

Tags: graph-theory

For every $c ∈ N$, let $f(c)$ be the $c$-color Ramsey number $R(3,3,...,3)$ - that is, the smallest integer $n$ such that any $c$-coloring of the edges of $K_n$ contains a monochromatic triangle.

Show that $f(c_1+c_2)−1≥(f(c_1)−1)·(f(c_2)−1)$.

By multiplication on the RHS I assume I need to split the graph up into two parts, but that's as far as I have been able to reason and insight would be appreciated.